# TOKEN_MANDATORY_LABEL and TokenIntegrityLevel not declared in this scope?

Tags: c++, windows, mingw

**Got the error :**
`TOKEN_MANDATORY_LABEL` and T`okenIntegrityLevel` not declared in this scope.

I included `windows.h` and `winnt.h` :

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <winnt.h>
```

I can redefine `TOKEN_MANDATORY_LABEL`:

```
typedef struct _TOKEN_MANDATORY_LABEL {
  SID_AND_ATTRIBUTES Label;
} TOKEN_MANDATORY_LABEL, *PTOKEN_MANDATORY_LABEL;
```

So the problem is *solved* for `TOKEN_MANDATORY_LABEL`, but if I redefine `TOKEN_INFORMATION_CLASS` for `TokenIntegrityLevel` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winnt/ne-winnt-_token_information_class) got the message that `TOKEN_INFORMATION_CLASS` was already declared. I'm compiling using MinGW :
`g++ sandbox.cpp -o sandbox.exe` I probably forget to include something.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is the problem you try to solve? Why are you attempting to redefine symbols or even structures? And remember that symbols starting with an underscore and followed by an upper-case letter (like e.g. `_TOKEN_MANDATORY_LABEL`) are [reserved for the compiler and standard library everywhere](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier).

Comment: I don't want to redefine anything, did you even read my post? It's just a workaround because I got those error : `error: 'TOKEN_MANDATORY_LABEL' was not declared in this scope` and `error: 'TokenIntegrityLevel' was not declared in this scope`. I just want my program to compile.

Comment: how i understand you use not standard windows headers files from sdk, but very old files from g++

Comment: @RbMm so how can I fix that? by using visual studio?

Comment: task not in visual studio - but in header files and compiler. main - you need use header files from SDK/WDK which you can download from ms site. with this all this symbols will be defined. but how i can guess *g++* simply not understand this files, can not compile it. you need use *cl.exe* compiler. which shell you will be use - nothing affect